# Remove Duplicates + first occurrences

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

sorry but do anybody know how i can remove duplicate Rows AND the first Occurrence in Google Dataprep?

So both rows (duplicate row + 1. occurrence) will be deleteted?

col1,col2

john,simpson

will,farrell

john,simpson

elon,musk

will be:

col1,col2

will,farrell

elon,musk

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that there's a more efficient way for larger datasets, but my mind initially jumps to using grouping.

Conceptually what I'm talking about is using grouping (joins to the same data could also work) as a way to identify which rows *have* duplicates, then using a separate rule to filter them out.

**Here's a proof-of-concept recipe wrangle based on your sample data:**

```
groupby group: col1,col2 value: COUNT() type: flatAgg

filter type: greaterThan col: row_count greaterThan: 1 action: Delete

drop col: row_count action: Drop
```

(if you paste these into new recipe steps one at a time, it will create them for you)

Note in the above that you don't have to pass a parameter to `COUNT()` in this case—it will just count the number of rows in each group (similar to `COUNT(*)` in SQL).

You can also see that I'm using the `flatAgg` type, which corresponds to the "Group by as new column(s)" option in the Group By step.  This is incredibly helpful in scenarios where you have many columns you don't want to have to re-specify like you would in a normal Group By (which creates a new table with *only* your columns). To help clarify this, here's what the settings should look like for this step:
[image: Google Cloud Dataprep Group By recipe step showing the flatAgg or "as new columns" grouping type]

Hope that helps, and happy wrangling!